# Can't connect to my swarm

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-cloud

I imported my swarm to docker cloud. I have 2 machines in the cloud and the third machine is mine. I want to connect the swarm (meaning - running commands from one of the managers in my machine - worker node - **currect me if I'm wrong**).

Connect to stavalfi/swarm1: (the first command is what docker cloud tell me to run)

```
root@stavalfi:~# docker run --rm -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e DOCKER_HOST dockercloud/client stavalfi/swarm1
=> You can now start using the swarm stavalfi/swarm1 by executing:
    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:32768
root@stavalfi:~# export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:32768
root@stavalfi:~# docker ps
Error response from daemon: Get https://cuiez4n2tvdbjt0acbug84tgz.direct.docker.cloud:2376/v1.32/containers/json: dial tcp: lookup cuiez4n2tvdbjt0acbug84tgz.direct.docker.cloud on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

When I try to enter: http://localhost:32768/ from chorme, I get:

```
Get https://cuiez4n2tvdbjt0acbug84tgz.direct.docker.cloud:2376/: dial tcp: lookup cuiez4n2tvdbjt0acbug84tgz.direct.docker.cloud on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

Also I'm running client_proxy_stavalfi_swarm1 image:

```
stavalfi@stavalfi:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
1980c6e430d9        dockercloud/client-proxy   "/client-proxy"     14 hours ago        Up 16 minutes       127.0.0.1:32768->2375/tcp   client_proxy_stavalfi_swarm1
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: any clue? I have the same problem. The interesting part is, I can deploy from Mac.